# How to implement ManyToMany relationship in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, many-to-many, mybatis

I'm recently learning to develop Web Applications using Java frameworks.

The application is just a basic register/login/logout system. Guests can register an account and login as a `common user`. Besides `common user`, there're two other roles `super admin` and `admin`, with their respective permissions/previleges.

An `Account` could own several `Role`s simultaneously, and of course a `Role` can be applied to many `Account`s. And that forms a many-to-many(or n-to-to) relationship between `Account` and `Role`.

I've maintained three tables in my database:

- First, the `ACCOUNT` table, which stores information of an account except the account's roles;
- Second, the `ROLE` table, which stores information about how many `Role`s there are. Currently, there are only three, "Superuser", "Admin" and "Common User";
- Third one, the `ACCOUNT_ROLE` table, which stores the mapping between `ACCOUNT` and `ROLE`.

I can implement this using Hibernate's `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` annotations, if I do so, **the third table can be automatically managed by Hibernate**. For example, when I create an `Account` of `Common User`, hibernate will help me add an entry which contains the `AccountId` and `RoleId` into the third table; and when I delete this `Account`, hibernate will help me drop the corresponding entry in the third table.

And, the question is **How can I implement this many-to-many relationship in MyBatis?**

I've read some materials introducing how to set up `one-to-one` or `one-to-many` relationship in MyBatis. But it seems that MyBatis doesn't have the `many-to-many` relationship like Hibernate. So what am I gonna do?

My raw idea is *Manage The Third Table Manually*, which means:

- I have to add entries to the third table manually, when I create a new account
- I have to remove/update corresponding entries manually, when I delete/update an account

Since I'm not really that familiar with MyBatis, this way is the only idea I can come up with now.

I hope someone could give me some tips or ideas or concrete samples about rounding off this problem.

*PLUS*: I've the demo application's code on [github](https://github.com/YigWoo/user-manage), in case you need to see how this demo goes.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### User story

First, MyBatis generate model, mapper, and `mapper.xml` for you.

Now, if you have two models -- User & Role 
What's the relationship between User and Role?

A user have many roles, and a role can be authorized to many users.
So they are `many-to-many` relationship.

### How to implement?

- add List roles to User model

  ```
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- add List users to Role model

  ```
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- make a UserRoleMapper interface to add some methods

  ```java
    package com.jim.mapper;

    import com.jim.model.Role;
    import com.jim.model.User;

    import java.util.List;

    public interface UserRoleMapper {
        int deleteRole(long userId, long roleId);
        int addRole(long userId, long roleId);
        List<Role> getRoles(long userId);
        List<User> getUsers(long roleId);
    }
  ```
- add a xml to mapping SQL & result.

  ```xml
    <resultMap id="UserResultMap" type="com.jim.model.Role">
        <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id"/>
        <result column="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name"/>
        <collection javaType="ArrayList" property="users" resultMap="RoleResultMap" />
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="RoleResultMap" type="com.jim.model.User">
        <id column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="id"/>
        <result column="username" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="username"/>
        <collection javaType="ArrayList" property="roles" resultMap="UserResultMap" />
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="addRole">
        INSERT INTO user_role (userId, roleId)
        VALUES (#{userId, jdbcType=BIGINT}, #{roleId, jdbcType=BIGINT});
    </insert>
    <delete id="deleteRole" >
        DELETE FROM user_role
        WHERE 1=1
        AND userId=#{userId}
        AND roleId=#{roleId}
    </delete>

    <select id="getRoles" resultMap="UserResultMap">
        SELECT
        r.id AS id, r.name AS name
        FROM users AS  u
        LEFT JOIN user_role AS ur ON u.id = ur.userId
        LEFT JOIN roles AS r ON r.id = ur.roleId
        WHERE 1=1
          AND u.id = #{id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
          AND r.isActive = 1
          AND u.isActive = 1
    </select>

    <select id="getUsers" resultMap="RoleResultMap">
        SELECT
        u.id AS id, u.username AS username
        FROM roles AS  r
        LEFT JOIN user_role AS ur ON r.id = ur.roleId
        LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ur.userId
        WHERE 1=1
        AND r.id = #{id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
        AND r.isActive = 1
        AND u.isActive = 1
    </select>
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Nested Resultmaps section in the doc.

That should be achieved with a result map like

```
<resultMap id="xx" type="map"> 
    <association id="key1" javaType="bean1" /> 
    <collection id="key2" ofType="bean2" /> 
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look in my [repository](https://github.com/eddumelendez/spring-dataaccess/tree/master/spring-dataaccess-mybatis) There are an example.

Comment: Did you mean to link this https://github.com/eddumelendez/mybatis-spring/ repository? Your link has expired it seems.